# Android LiveData - switchMap is not triggered on second update

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-livedata, android-architecture-lifecycle

I have a `LiveData` object that depends on another `LiveData`. As I understand, `Transformations.switchMap` should allow to chain them. But `switchMap` handler is triggered only once and it doesn't react on further updates. If instead I use `observe` on the first object and, when it's ready, retrieve the second, it works fine but in this case I have to do it in `Activity` rather than `ViewModel`. Is it possible to chain `LiveData` objects, like `Transformations.switchMap`, but receive all updates, not only the first one?

Here is an attempt to use `switchMap`:

```
LiveData<Resource<User>> userLiveData = usersRepository.get();
return Transformations.switchMap(userLiveData, resource -> {
    if (resource.status == Status.SUCCESS && resource.data != null) {
        return apiService.cartItems("Bearer " + resource.data.token);
    } else {
        return AbsentLiveData.create();
    }
});
```

Here is an approach with `observe` in activity (works but requires to keep logic in activity):

```
viewModel.user().observe(this, x -> {
    if (x != null && x.data != null) {
        viewModel.items(x.data.token).observe(this, result -> {
            // use result
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi, did you find the solution?

Comment: Hi, yes, posted it below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround, I used `MediatorLiveData`. I add the result of the first call as a source and, when it's ready, replace it with a final call:

```
MediatorLiveData<MyResponse> result = new MediatorLiveData<>();
LiveData<Resource<User>> source = this.get();
result.addSource(source, resource -> {
    if (resource.status == Status.SUCCESS && resource.data != null) {
        result.removeSource(source);
        result.addSource(apiService.cartItems("Bearer " + resource.data.token), result::postValue);
    }
});
return result;
```

Comment: I think it was ViewModel, but could be either way, depending on the app architecture

Answer (score 3):

I was trying to do something similar to you. I have a LiveData `something`, and when that changes I want to query `somethingElse` from the DB based on a property. Because the property can be null, if I query the DB with it, I'll get an exception. Therefore, if the property is null, I'm returning an empty MutableLiveData.

I have noticed, that when I returned this empty MutableLiveData, the observers that subscribed to `somethingElse` were not getting any updates. I saw that on your [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48006739/1952996) you ended up using a MediatorLiveData. Then I steped through my code with the debugger and noticed that the switchMap also uses a MediatorLiveData.

After experimenting a bit, I realised that when creating the empty MutableLiveData, it's initial value is null and won't trigger any updates. If I explicitly set the value, then it will notify the observers.

```
somethingElse = Transformations.switchMap(something, somethingObject -> {
                if (something.someProperty() != null) {
                    return repository.getSomethingElseByProperty(something.someProperty());
                }else{
                    MutableLiveData<SomethingElse> empty = new MutableLiveData<>();
                    empty.setValue(null);//need to set a value, to force update of observers
                    return empty;
                }
```

The code here has worked for me. In the question, you use an AbsentLiveData, which I don't know how it is implemented, so I'm not sure it would work exactly in that case.

Comment: Thank you so much, I had it above and for whatever reason it did not work until I updated my filter inside the switchmap function.